# Custom Search bar on iOS which will look like normal textField

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to implement **search bar** on iOS which will look like screenshot:

[image]

Supported iOS versions: iOS6+ .

What I know: I can use **UITextField** on Navigation bar.

What I'm looking For: **Customize UISearchBar**.

Comment: Customise UISearchBar?? but can you explain what do you want to customise, just background ?

Comment: Normal UISearchBar won't look like one which is in screenshot, I want to customize its appearance so that it will look like this.

Comment: UISearchBar appearance is very customizable. Read the documentation.

Comment: unclear question what you want exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can search using a `UITextField` too. In that case you can simply add a `UIImageView` to the background of your `UITextField` where the `UITextField` would have No border. You would have to create 2 arrays one for the searching content and another the original array.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    searchString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if([string length]==0)
    {
        [searchedArray removeAllObjects];
    }
    else
    {
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Label CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
        searchedArray = [[maineArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];
    }
    [TableView reloadData];
    return YES;
}
```

Where "Label" is the value to be search upon. Please do tell if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're trying to make an iOS app look like Android.  Your users will expect it to have an iOS feel.  Nevertheless, you can accomplish this with some Photoshop magic.  Create the bottom "box" piece as a png image, and also grab/create an image of a magnifying glass.  Create a UIView that has both images as UIImageViews in them, as well as a UITextField for handling input.